# Solving the differential equation of bass diffusion model using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

http://www.bassbasement.org/F/N/FMB/Pubs/Bass%201969%20New%20Prod%20Growth%20Model.pdf
About the bass diffusion model, you can refer to the link given above. It's used to predict the adoption of new products.

Using the method below and the condition that F(0)=0, I want to get F(t), and F'(t)

```
  DSolve[{F′(t)=p+(q−p)∗F(t)−q∗(F[t])^2 }, F,t]
```

Any suggestions? Please post your answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
k = DSolve[{f'[t] == p + (q - p) f[t] - q f[t]^2,  f[0] == 0}, f, t]
```

Please ... try to read the manuals!

**Edit**

Perhaps Plotting it requires some expertise:

```
g[x_?NumericQ] := (f /. k[[1]] /. {p -> 1/3, q -> 2/3})[x]
Plot[{g[t], g'[t]}, {t, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: I had ran this code too. however, MM issues an warning:   Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

Comment: @FrankWANG That is because there are also trivial solutions try **Reduce[f'[t] == p + (q - p) f[t] - q (f[t])^2]**